# OData implementation for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, odata

We have a fairly straight forward line of business application implemented with ASP.NET MVC2 and we have a new requirement to be able to share our data with other parts of the business, which include SharePoint 2010, Ruby and Python.

I'd like to use OData as the transport mechanism (as opposed to SOAP) using our existing MVC application. I'm struggling to find anyone mentioning an implementation of an OData provider for MVC.

Can you suggest either how I might be able to start rolling my own OData ASP.NET MVC provider or point me to somewhere which might have already started something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You could check this out

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43991/implement-odata-api-for-stackoverflow

implemented here https://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: Barry - thanks for the link. I think what I was really searching for was a pure ASP.NET MVC OData implementation, but it looks like the WCF DataService route is a straight forward way to go.

Answer (score 0):

OData with MVC is extremely easy to getup and going with MVC Web API.

e.g. Your OData controller would look like this:

```
public class ProductController : EntitySetController<Product, int>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public ProductController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public override IQueryable<Product> Get()
    {
        return _unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().Query().Get();
    }

    protected override Product GetEntityByKey(int key)
    {
        return _unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().FindById(key);
    }

    protected override Product UpdateEntity(int key, Product update)
    {
        update.State = ObjectState.Modified;
        _unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().Update(update);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
        return update;
    }

    public override void Delete([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        _unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().Delete(key);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _unitOfWork.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

A detailed walk-through can be seen here: **http://blog.longle.net/2013/06/18/mvc-4-web-api-odata-entity-framework-kendo-ui-grid-datasource-with-mvvm/**